# About tar headers

Tags: linux, header, gnu, tar, manpage

I'm trying to understand the first line of a tar file header. The archive was created using `tar --format=v7`.

Here is the line in question:

> Makefile0000644000175000001440000000072612644013631007440 00000000000000

First letters are the name of the file. What do the following numbers mean?

Answer (score 0):

0000644 probably refers to the permissions, after that you'll have things like date/time created, owner information, etc.

Comment: i Have this to : struct posix_header
{                              
  char name[100];
  char mode[8];
  char uid[8];
  char gid[8];
  char size[12];
  char mtime[12];
  char chksum[8];
  char typeflag;
  char linkname[100];
  char magic[6];
  char version[2];
  char uname[32];
  char gname[32];
  char devmajor[8];
  char devminor[8];
  char prefix[155];
                                
};

Comment: @Xjames56X If you have that information, it should tell you how to interpret everything in the file.